# Turning off animation in HighCharts globally

Tags: javascript, animation, highcharts

I am using HighCharts for producing multi-panel charts with multiple series. As far as I can tell, the only way to stop the animation is to use an

```
animation: false
```

atrribution for the plotOptions attribute set for each chart, and then again for each series. Is there a way of setting animaiton off by default for all charts drawn?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Yes, you have to use `Highcharts.setOptions`.
This way you can set default options for all your charts.

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            animation: false
        }
    }
});
```

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Highcharts

Answer (score 1):

if still not disabling the animation, after setting

```
 plotOptions: {
    series: {
        animation: false
    }
 }
```

in `highcharts.js` find

```
plotOptions : {
        line : {
            allowPointSelect : !1,
            showCheckbox : !1,
            animation : {
                duration : 0
            },
```

Here I have set the animation duration 0, it works :)

Comment: This works with the dotnet version! Thanks! (column chart)

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the animations globally in highcharts by doing:

```
chart: {
  animation: false
},
```

Reference: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.animation